# How to use type name in enum

Tags: c#

How can I do the following?

```
public enum SlideSize { full, half, short };
```

Do I have to do something like this?

```
public enum SlideSize { full, half, [Description("short")] shortSlide };
```

Unfortunately my workaround behaves like a string.

Comment: If you want to use a keyword as an identifier, preface every use of it with an at sign (`@`), so `@short`. It quickly gets tedious, so using Pascal casing is easier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enums should be in [Pascal case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/4x252001(v=vs.71)).

```
public enum SlideSize { Full, Half, Short };
```

If you follow that convention, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 5):

The [`@` symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) can be used to tell the compiler that you want to use a keyword as a variable name.

```cs
public enum SlideSize { full, half, @short };
```

Though I would recommend following John Wu's answer.